# Vector valued Function: Find the tangent line that is parallel to the vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A curve is defined by

() = ^  + ^2  + ^3 k,  ∈ R

Find the tangent line that is parallel to the vector i + 4j + 12k

Comment: did you mean tangent to the curve at the point $<1,4,12>?$

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the tangent line at a point $t$ is given by the componentwise derivative

$$\mathbf r'(t)=e^t\mathbf i+2e^{2t}\mathbf j+3e^{3t}\mathbf k$$

Notice that when $t=\ln2$, we have $\mathbf r'(\ln2)=2\mathbf i+8\mathbf j+24\mathbf k$ which is parallel to our given vector $\mathbf v=\mathbf i+4\mathbf j+12\mathbf k$ (i.e. $\mathbf r'(\ln 2)=2\mathbf v$). Hence, the problem is to find the tangent line at $\mathbf r(\ln 2)$. This is just the curve passing through the point $\mathbf r(\ln2)=2\mathbf i+4\mathbf j+8\mathbf k$ with slope $\mathbf r'(\ln2)$. That is, it is the line

$$\mathbf l(t)=(2+2t)\mathbf i+(4+8t)\mathbf j+(8+24t)\mathbf k.$$